# Kali linux - unable to run GUI

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation

I have downloaded kali from the official page, version `large 64bit`, after installation it doesn't show GUI. First, it shows all checks (I haven't seen any error there tho), after that it seems like it hangs out(?). I managed to go to console mode using ctrl+alt+F2. `startx` is undefined, `X` throws some strange content, gdm3 hangs. Tried running `apt-get update / apt-get upgrade / apt update / apt upgrade, installing gnome, gdm3, kali-linux-full, rebooting.` And still no gui. Switching `ctrl+alt+F2 -> ctrl+alt+F1` gives me black screen with `_` on top, can't type anything there.

The card is a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti.

Any idea what should I do? Reinstall linux (tried), redownload it on USB, use other kali distribution? (Using rufus to create bootable USB)

[image]
[image]

Tried to add `nomodeset`:
[image]

Comment: Make/model of device? Model of graphics card? Is it supported by Kali Linux?

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti

Comment: I'll try installing it on VM so if there are the same issues I can paste logs/ss

Comment: kali 64bit seems to be working on VM, I'll try reinstalling it on PC

Comment: Do you need to install it? Maybe it works well enough live or persistent live from a USB drive (pendrive or external SSD).

Comment: I cannot boot it up from usb. I mean. I get this "hello world" prompt, but live version does not boot (I get the loading then black screen + `_`) and installation still the same problem - i can install but black screen and `_`

Comment: added errors from log after using `X` command

Comment: Because of the nvidia card, try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Comment: @sudodus Tried, still black screen and `_`

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after editing the `/etc/default/grub` file?

Comment: yes i did, then i rebooted machine

Comment: Well, it seems from the screenshots that you have problems with the graphics. Kali is based on Debian, and the newest stable version is 10 'Buster'. Please try if you can boot Debian 10 live and/or install it and get the graphics working. You can add `nomodeset` temporarily at grub (if UEFI mode) or at syslinux (if BIOS mode) just for testing.

Comment: ow how can i add it to syslinux? I have just noticed that rufus uses this 'syslinux-6.04'. And for now I should try just downloading debian 10?

Comment: See this link: [boot options](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808)

Comment: Yes download an **iso file  of Debian 10 live with a desktop environment** (not 'standard'), and if you want the built-in version of syslinux you can use Rufus in 'dd-mode'.

Comment: ok so i downloaded debian-live-10.1.0-amd64-gnome.iso from https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/  . I hope it's a proper version. i'll give it a try. (and i was using dd-mode all the time since in ISO mode it wasn't working at all)

Comment: You can check it with the corresponding md5sum (from the same web-site). `md5sum debian-live-10.1.0-amd64-gnome.iso` and the output should match the sum at the web-site.

Comment: @sudodus couldn't run it either. It threw a bunch of errors, then debian logo appeared and then black screen with `_`

Comment: So it is a general problem with Debian 10 and the re-spin distros based on Debian 10. They cannot manage your computer. **Let us hope that someone will chip in and suggest what to do to solve the problem**. Maybe you have to try with another linux distro, for example Ubuntu, but if you want Kali because of its pentesting features, you have to wait ... or try with another computer, and it is more likely that you succeed in an old computer or a computer with simple built-in (Intel) graphics.

Comment: kali is just my most favorite distro of linux. I'm having it on my laptop and I had no problems with it whatsoever. It's kinda sad I can run it from VM on windows, but when I try standalone or even live version it doesn't work :/  Well, still, thanks for your time

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem @sudodus. `apt install nvidia-driver` and rebooting after this worked (also ran apt upgrade but probably it didn't do that much)

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem seemed to be as easy as installing a package, specifically:
`apt install nvidia-driver`
and rebooting after this. GUI appeared and worked nice and smoothly

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)